# Overloaded MySQL Connections & Not Respond Server

Tags: mysql

A few times a day, our database server does not shut down the processes in the sleep state and does not respond by slowing down access to the server. Here are two problems:

server 32gb ram etc. Although it is a machine that is higher than the average, 100-150 is starting to not respond to the "SLEEP connection", what is the reason?

PHP is used in our software after the query is processed in the DB class destruct method `mysqli_close` do. But it stays open on mysql server.

Can you help me?

Pics:

Connections: They all remain open until 30 seconds have expired (wait_timeout)

[image: They all remain open until 30 seconds have expired (wait_timeout)]

General status: average status

[image: average status]

Comment: Post a sample of your code - from connect to close, please.  Your my.cnf or my.ini NEEDS thread_cache_size=100   to reduce Threads Created count and minimize CPU time used breaking down/creating connections.  max_connections=1000 would likely be much better for you than current 5000.

Comment: Aborted Clients ~26000 and Aborted Connections ~4000 indicates something is interrupting your customers expectations for data delivery.  REFMAN has helpful information for your version.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info, including Skype ID, please.

Comment: Any chance we could Skype before Christmas?